# What is the name of the symbol $=$ in English?

Tags: notation, soft-question, terminology, convention

What is the name of the symbol $=$ in English? Wikipedia says people use "equals sign" than "equality". Is it right? Is it to avoid ambiguity between the equality formula $(x = y)$ and the equality symbol $=$?

The main my question is the following:
*can I call the symbol $=$ equality when it is obvious from the context?*

I'm writing a text like:

> The language of set theory uses the following symbols:
>
> - truth: $\top$
> - falsity: $\bot$
> - negation: $\neg$
> - conjunction: $\land$
> - disjunction: $\lor$
> - implication: $\Rightarrow$
> - biconditional: $\Leftrightarrow$
> - universal quantifier: $\forall$
> - existential quantifier: $\exists$
> - *equality*: $=$
> - membership: $\in$

Does this sound strange? I'm not sure because I have seen some mathematicians use the word "equality" for the symbol but perhaps they are not native English speakers.

Reply to some comments:

To @xander-henderson:
For example, there are many famous propositions like Cauchy-Schwarz in**equality**. It is a proposition or a well-formed formula, not a symbol itself.

To @jmoravitz:
In Japanese, the proposition $x = y$ is only called "等式" or "方程式", and the symbol $=$ is only called "等号". The proposition $x \le y$ is called "不等式" and the symbol $\le$ is called "不等号". So I don't have any idea whether it is okay or not. Calling both "inequality" is like calling both "不等". So I'm afraid "equals sign" feels like too colloquial, but I'm not a native English speaker, it's unreliable. I have seen at least Japanese and Ukrainian mathematician uses "equality" as a symbol in some obvious contexts. But Wikipedia says "equals sign" is popular. So I asked.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you are making here.  Can you explain the differing contexts in which you believe that there is ambiguity?

Comment: "*When it is obvious from the context*" it would be obvious from context, so go ahead.  Language is fluid and there are no hard rules.  That said, I personally would feel weird referring to the literal character `=` in the context of its existence as a character as "equality" rather than "the equals symbol" or "the equals sign" but it really shouldn't matter in the long run.

Comment: "*There are many famous propositions like Cauchy-Schwarz inequality*"  That is referring to the entirety of all of what follows in red: $\color{red}{|\langle u,v\rangle |^2\leq \langle u,u\rangle \cdot \langle v,v\rangle}$.  That is not referring just to what follows in blue: $|\langle u,v\rangle |^2\color{blue}{\leq} \langle u,u\rangle \cdot \langle v,v\rangle$.  If talking about the symbol as it appears on a keyboard and not talking about the contextual statements in which it appears, it is better understood to still call it *a symbol*.

Comment: I can't grasp why my post is closed. Some people use the word equality as a symbol, but I don't know it is a common practice or will be accepted in native English speakers. Some people use "equality" as a proposition itself. There is a room to be ambiguous. My question is about it.

Comment: Your context disambiguates the two meanings, viz. you state that you are listing set-theory *symbols*, so you can simply write "equality" instead of "equality symbol". Ditto for:  negation, conjunction, disjunction, implication, biconditional.

Comment: FWIW, the Unicode name for U+003D `=` is "equals sign".  But they also call the backslash "reverse solidus", which nobody in real life does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Logic, almost all logicians **do** use "equality" to refer to "=" as in "FOL with[out] equality", as short for "equality symbol". Mathematicians in general prefer to refer to "=" as "equals sign" or "equality sign" or "equality symbol" (with the explicit "symbol"). Yes, "equality" can also refer to a formula of the form "$s = t$". Somewhat amusingly, a formula of the form "$s ≠ t$" is instead called an "inequation" and *not* an "inequality".

To answer your question, no, it is not a grammatical mistake. This is why we say "FOL with[out] equality". If "equality" can only refer to equations rather than the symbol "=", then this phrase would be ungrammatical. But it is perfectly fine. For an example right here on Math SE, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185507) where Noah Schweber repeatedly unambiguously uses "equality" to refer to "=".

And I would prefer not to think of this as 'just a matter of context', because one cannot just drop arbitrary words in general; ultimately it still comes down to whether it is acceptable in current mathematical vernacular. In English, it is as I said above. In other languages, it may be a totally different story.

Comment: Another example: in ring theory "identity" can mean the multiplicative neutral element (usually denoted $1)$ or a (ring language) equality that holds true for all free variables, e.g. $\,x + y = y + x.\,$ We study rings with both types of identities, but the latter is usually disambiguated by the name "rings with *polynomial* identity", e.g. [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1948-54-06/S0002-9904-1948-09049-8/S0002-9904-1948-09049-8.pdf), and [Jacobson's famous proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41845/242) that rings with identity $\,x^n - x\,$ are commutative.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Yes, and in logic some people even refer to "=" as "identity" as in "FOL with[out] identity", though it is less common now. Funnily, google search results yield ( "first-order logic with equality" : "first-order logic with identity" ) = 16.6 million : 17.3 thousand but ( "first-order logic without equality" : "first-order logic without identity" ) = 4780 : 5290. As if "identity" was more common for "=" in the past along with FOL without equality, whereas now FOL with equality has almost entirely taken over together with the modern use of "equality" for "=".

Answer (score 3):

As a practicing mathematician, I'd call it "the equality symbol". "The equals sign" sounds clumsier. As some people have commented, "equality" would suggest to me "an equality", which would be a phrase like $x=y$, not just the symbol $=$.

Answer (score 2):

> - truth: $\top$
> - falsity: $\bot$
> - negation: $\neg$
> - conjunction: $\land$
> - disjunction: $\lor$
> - implication: $\Rightarrow$
> - biconditional: $\Leftrightarrow$
> - universal quantifier: $\forall$
> - existential quantifier: $\exists$
> - *equality*: $=$
> - membership: $\in$

To me, this is not merely a list of symbol names, but a list of syntactic elements. So, $=$ is the **equality** *relation*, $∨$ is the disjunction *connective*, $∃$ is the existential *quantifier*, etc. This answers the question of whether to call item 10 ‘equals sign’ or ‘equality’.

And could we please call item 6 ‘conditional’ [rather than](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884866/21813) ‘implication’, particularly since you are calling item 7 ‘*bi*conditional’? (Also, many modern texts use the symbols $→$ and $↔,$ rather than $⇒$ and $⇔,$ for the material conditional and the material biconditional.)