# How to prove the inequality including Bessel functions?

Tags: inequality, bessel-functions

As well-known the modified Bessel functions of orders zero and one of the first kind, $I_0(x)$ and $I_1(x)$ are positive and increasing functions over $x\in(0, \infty)$, while the modified Bessel functions of orders zero and one of the second kind, $K_0(x)$ and $K_1(x)$ are positive and decreasing functions over $x\in(0, \infty)$.

How can I prove the following inequality with $\alpha>1$ and $k>0$?

$$I_0(k\alpha)K_1[k(\alpha-1)]-K_0(k\alpha)I_1[k(\alpha-1)]>0.$$

In other words, how to prove $I_0(x)K_1(y)>K_0(x)I_1(y)$ with $x>y>0$?

I believe the  inequality is true as can be observed by plotting. Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: [Inequation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequation) or inequality?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Indeed, ["inequality"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4475420/21820).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce the function
$$
f(x,t)=I_0(x+t)K_1(x)-K_0(x+t)I_1(x).
$$
We want to show that $f(x,t)>0$ for all $x>0,t\geq 0$.

Consider first the case $f(x,0)$. We can prove that $f(x,0)>0$ by writing
$$
f(x,0)=(I_0(x)-I_1(x))K_1(x)+I_1(x)(K_1(x)-K_0(x))
$$
and using the monotonicity properties (see here: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.37)
$$
I_0(x)>I_1(x)\mbox{ and }K_1(x)>K_0(x)\mbox{ for all }x>0.
$$

Next, by a direct computation, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t) =I_1( t + x) K_1(x) + I_1(x)K_1(t + x)
$$
which is manifestly positive for $x>0,t\geq 0$. Hence
$$
f(x,t)=f(x,0)+\int_0^t (I_1( \tau+ x) K_1(x) + I_1(x)K_1(\tau + x))\mathrm d \tau>0.
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer! Is there a typo in line 2 of the [link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.37): $0<\nu<\infty$ should be changed to $0\le\nu<\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want to prove that, *for the worst case*,
$$f(x)=I_0(x)\, K_1(x)-I_1(x)\, K_0(x)~>~0$$

It is simple if you consider small and large values of $x$.

Using their asymptotic values,

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+O\left(x\right)$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

If you want to go further, use Hankel's asymptotic values which will give
$$f(x) =  \frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{3}{16 x^4}-\frac{45}{32768
   x^6}+\cdots$$ which is extremely good as soon as $x>\frac 32$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Should your function $f$ have two independent variables, that is, $f(x,y)$ with $x>y>0$. Btw, could you please give the asymptotic form of $I_0$, $K_0$, $I_1$ and $K_1$, respectively, since I found it is not that clear in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). Thank you again!

Comment: @user95273. I used Hankel's formulations which are on the Wikipedia page